# Additive group with out element 0 and generator should n't be 1

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples

The additive group $\mathbb{Z}_n$  for any natural number $n$ forms an additive group which has 0 as identity element and 1 as generator.

Please provide me few examples of additive groups (with integer elements) like above with out element 0 and generator should n't be 1.

What I mean is if $\mathbb{A}$ is an additive group with $i$,$g$ as identity and generator elements  of $\mathbb{A}$ then $i\ne 0$ and $0 \not \in \mathbb{A}$ and $g \ne 1$.

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean. Do you want a group on $\mathbb{Z}$, with an operation $\oplus$, which is commutative, but $0$ and $1$ are not identity and generator respectively? If so, choose a bijection $f:\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$, where $f(0,0) \neq 0$, then transport the standard group structure onto $\mathbb{Z}$. So $n\oplus m=f(x) \oplus f(y):=f(x+y)$ would define an abelian group on $\mathbb{Z}$. If that is not what you are looking for, then you need to make your question more clear.

Comment: @PaulPlummer 0 should not present in that additive group.

Comment: Oh, I see. How about a bijection $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$ and $f(1) \neq 1$, and do a similar transport of the structure as in the above case... Is that what you are looking for? I am not really sure what you mean by an "additive group", what is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be implicit in the question that $\mathbb Z_n$ is an additive group of integers, i.e. a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$. This is not the case. $\mathbb Z_n=\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is the group of residue classes modulo $n$. Its elements are often represented by integers, but they are not integers (else $1$ would generate all of $\mathbb Z$), but classes of integers, e.g. the element of $\mathbb Z_n$ often represented by $1$ is $\{kn+1\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}$.

The only subgroups of $\mathbb Z$ are the groups $n\mathbb Z$ with $n\in\mathbb N$. They have $0$ as their identity, and more generally, any subgroup of a group inherits the identity element of the group. This is because it inherits the binary operation of the group, and the binary operation by definition only has that one identity element.

Thus, there are no groups of integers of the kind that you are looking for. You'd have to define a different group operation to get one (and then it would be questionable whether it still makes sense to call the objects "integers").

Answer (score 1):

Since $0$ is the additive identity, you have to have $0$.

You can have groups without $1$. for example

```
 {..., -6,  -4,  -2,  0,  2,  4,  6, ...}
```